# How to fill the selected UV island with colour when texture painting?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, texture-painting

I am trying to color parts of the UV map below with the paint function.

[image: UV mapping that has to be colored]

My problem is that I don't know how to select the square in the UVeditor so to be able to fill it simply with the desired color instead of having to paint it by hand as you can see here:

[image: Upper left square to be colored; long and imperfect way by hand]

My goal is once again to have the upper left square in the UVeditor, which corresponds to a face of the cube, completely colored. 
How can I tell blender to fill with a desired color a part of the UV mapped mesh? I need to have a clear distinction between the colors of the faces and with the coloring procedure by hand this is quite impossible, especially for more complicated meshes...

Answer (score 14):

- Go to edit mode
- select the faces you want to paint on
- Turn on texture painting, in the header of this window turn on the button named "face selection masking for painting", an icon with a cube with a face red/white
- choose the "fill" brush
- clic on a face
- done!

Use "shift" key to select/deselect faces without entering edit mode

Answer (score 4):

[image]

The icon has just changed to a white box

Answer (score 1):

This is an elaboration on what @josh sanfelici stated. I tried finding the "face selection masking for painting" button and found it at the bottom of the main viewing window (see below).

[image]

Comment: I couldn't find it in Blender 2.80.
Was it removed?

Answer (score 0):

Oookay just wanted to clarify [the button John McCarthy shows in his answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/146124/67679) because I was [with Sami Ben and couldn't find that button at all](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28463/how-to-fill-the-selected-uv-island-with-colour-when-texture-painting#comment229576_89724)!

Once you click the "Texture Paint" tab at the top, push TAB to enter edit mode, then select or ctrl+select the faces you want to paint, then push TAB to exit edit mode, THEN you get the button. You don't get the button in edit mode where you're selecting the faces!

New to Blender, took me a solid 15 minutes to figure it out and this was the top result when I was googling around, so hope this helps someone in the future!